# Should the native vlan be explicitly declared as an allowed vlan

Tags: vlan, lan

Should the native vlan be explicitly declared as an allowed vlan for a trunk port or not to send/receive frames of that native vlan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using the native VLAN, there is no need to allow it on the trunk.  If you do want to send/receive traffic on that VLAN then yes, allow it.